# SSRS INSTR Compare function when both fields are blank

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm comparing 2 fields in SSRS using the `instr function` and giving a conditional color format when one of the fields is different.  The below code works perfectly except when both fields are blank or have nothing.  When they are both blank or have nothing then I still get the conditional color and I don't want any color when both are blank or nothing in the field.  It just needs to be transparent with no color.

Here's my code.  Can I add `isnothing` or something like this to the code?

```
=iif(instr(Fields!AF_ADDRESS4.Value, Fields!BF_ADDRESS4.Value)>0,"Transparent","Yellow")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do something like that. Add another IIF in front of your expression to check that both fields have values before you run this. Give it a try!

Comment: I tried several attempts and not able to get this to work.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Add what you have tried to the question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with.  Removed the `instr function` to make this work.  This works just as expected.  Actually, this can just replace the `instr function` because it pulls everything that is different between the 2 fields.

```
=iif((Fields!AF_ADDRESS4.Value) = (fields!BF_ADDRESS4.Value),"transparent","Yellow")
```